# Simle redirect report No such file or directory

Tags: linux, redirect

My Simple bash script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo < "$(ls /)"
```

when I run

```
bash -i test.sh
```

it reports:

```
bash: bin
boot
dev
etc
home
initrd.img
lib
lib64
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
vmlinuz: No such file or directory
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`command < file` will redirect a *file* into the standard input of a command. `"$(ls /)"` isn't a file name, nor does `echo` read standard input, so redirection isn't the right tool to use. Leave it out:

```
echo "$(ls /)"
```

There's no reason to use `$()` to capture `ls`'s output if you're just going to `echo` that output. You can get rid of both and simply call `ls` directly:

```
ls /
```

Comment: I just use this as a simple example. I find that when I change '<' to '<<<' , it works.